# InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:)

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have just updated to `Swift 3` in `Xcode`, and I cannot figure out what to do with this error. Can anyone help ???

**Error:** **InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at thumbnailUrlFromStorage**. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.

My code is:

```
// Create a url for data (tumbnail image)
self.fileUrl = metaData?.downloadURLs![0].absoluteString
if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser) != nil {
    let idRoom = self.BASE_REF.child("rooms").childByAutoId()
    idRoom.setValue(["caption": caption, "thumbnailUrlFromStorage": self.storageRef.child(metaData!.path!).description, "fileUrl": self.fileUrl])
```

Comment: you are trying to  dictionary or array in your idRoom ? can you please explain which type of value you want there ?

Comment: I am trying to save the data into a Firebase database called Room. Later I want to call the data into another ViewController. The func is like this 

 "func  CreateNewRoom(_ user: FIRUser, caption: String, data: Data) {
        let filePath = "Thumbnail/\(user.uid)/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))"
        let metaData =  FIRStorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
        storageRef.child(filePath).put(data, metadata:  metaData) { (metaData, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error uploading:")
                return"

Answer (score 2):

```
if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser) != nil {
  let idRoom = self.BASE_REF.child("rooms").childByAutoId()
  let thumbnailUrlFromStorage: String = self.storageRef.child(metaData!.path!).description

  let data: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
    "caption": caption,
    "thumbnailUrlFromStorage": thumbnailUrlFromStorage,
    "fileUrl": self.fileUrl
  ]

  idRoom.setValue(data)
}
```

Not sure if this could work since I didn't have the opportunity to run it but to me looks like you were passing `self.storageRef.child(metaData!.path!).description` as nil.

Comment: no problem @CarstenHøvsgaard and don't forget to accept the answer 